# update database in phonegap

Tags: ajax, sqlite, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm getting the following error:

> Uncaught Error: INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11

I get this error message when trying to execute a query.

Did anyone ever get the same problem ?

```
function populateDB(tx) {

    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ORDERS');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ORDERS (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, client_ID, status)');

    var myurl="xml.xml";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: myurl, 
        dataType: "xml", 
        success: onSuccess
    }); 
}

function onSuccess(xml) {

    $(xml).find('articles').each(function () {
        var idord = $(this).attr('id');

        var esql ='INSERT INTO ORDERS (id, client_ID, status) VALUES ('+idord+', 4, "done" )';
        var nameclient = $(this).find('name').text();
        $('.items').append('<h2>'+ nameclient '</h2>').appendTo('#xml-data'); 

        tx.executeSql(esql) ;
    });  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try defining your function `onSuccess` inside your function `populateDB` as follows:

```
function populateDB(tx) {

    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ORDERS');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ORDERS (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, client_ID, status)');

    var myurl="xml.xml";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: myurl, 
        dataType: "xml", 
        success: function(xml) {

            $(xml).find('articles').each(function () {
                var idord = $(this).attr('id');

                var esql ='INSERT INTO ORDERS (id, client_ID, status) VALUES ('+idord+', 4, "done" )';
                var nameclient = $(this).find('name').text();
                $('.items').append('<h2>'+ nameclient '</h2>').appendTo('#xml-data'); 

                tx.executeSql(esql) ;
            });  
        }

    }); 
}
```

Let me know if this works mate.

Comment: Thank's,for fast answer, but I tryed this way at first,and then made function aside. Unfortunately, I've the same result. Now I try to figure out why function is't see the object 'tx' and doesn't make query.